# How can I send an email using SharePoint Web Service Access?

Tags: asp.net, email, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I'm developing an external ASP.NET app that will sit inside a SharePoint site. Can I use SharePoint services to send an email? The app will specify the email content (subject, to, from, and body). I just want to call a method on the SharePoint service to have it send the email.

I'm using WSS 3.0 (not MOSS). Is this possible? If not, what are possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method to send email. Add reference to SharePoint DLL and then you can use this method. This way you wil be using your WS site's email configuration.

Comment: Anyway I can use this to send reminder emails too? I understand this is not possible with an web app and that the best way is to use a Windows Service.

Comment: Yes  a Windows Service is better or a SharePoint timer job is also a good option.